# Como puedo iterar el str de una clase que esta compuesta por una lista

Tags: python, poo, clase

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Estoy haciendo ejercicios de POO en Python y en el ejercicio tengo un problema al momento de llamar el **str** de una clase ya que lo tengo compuesto por una lista de 2 instancia de una clase diferente. Solo me arroja la primera instancia. El error lo tengo en el Listado de Clientes. Solo me arroja el primer cliente

```py
class Cliente:

    def __init__(self, dni, nombre, apellidos):
        self.dni = dni
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellidos = apellidos

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.nombre, self.apellidos)

class Empresa:

    def __init__(self, clientes=[]):
        self.clientes = clientes

    def __str__(self):
        for c in self.clientes:
            return c.__str__()


hector = Cliente(nombre = "Hector", apellidos = "Costa Guzman", dni = "11111a")
juan = Cliente("22222b", "Juan", "Gonzalez Marquez")

empresa = Empresa(clientes=[hector, juan])

print("\n==LISTADO DE CLIENTES==")
print(empresa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `__str__()` siempre debe retornar una cadena de caracteres. En el caso de la clase `Empresa`, tienes que hacer algo con la lista de clientes para transformarla en una cadena. Tal como lo tienes, sólo retorna el primer clientes, finalizando el bucle.

Un modo de hacerlo:

```py
class Empresa:

    def __init__(self, clientes=[]):
        self.clientes = clientes

    def __str__(self):
        lista_clientes = ", ".join(str(cliente) for cliente in self.clientes)
        return "<Clientes: {}>".format(lista_clientes)
```

Convertimos los elementos de la lista en cadenas (invocando `str` para cada uno de ellos) y los unimos con `", "` a través del método `str.join`. Este *patrón* es muy común en python para obtener una cadena a partir de una lista.

Es mejor usar `str(cliente)` que invocar el método directamente `cliente.__str__()`. Hay objetos que no tienen defido el método `__str__()`, pero a los que aún pueden convertirse en cadena con `str()` (por ejemplo, por tener el método `__repr__()`).

Un último consejo: cuida cuando pases una lista como argumento. La lista de clientes que pasas para crear la instancia de `Empresa` se  pasa por referencia. Cualquier cambio que hagas después, repercutirá en el campo `self.clientes`.

Para evitar problemas, es conveniente copiar la lista:

```py
class Empresa:

    def __init__(self, clientes=[]):
        self.clientes = clientes[:]
....
```

De nuevo, usar `lista[:]` es otro *patrón* habitual en python para hacer copias de una lista simple. Se puede hacer aún más seguro, pero eso sería otro tema.

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion y el tiempo dedicado en ella. Es mas que todo una introduccion para ver como funciona la POO pero tendre en cuenta lo de las listas para ejercicios mas avanzados. Gracias nuevamente